# Room database error while deleting row onclick

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have defined a [room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) SQLite database as:

```
@Database(entities = {PlaceSaved.class},version = 1)
public abstract class PlaceDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract DatabaseInterface databaseInterface();

    @Override
    protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration config) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected InvalidationTracker createInvalidationTracker() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

with definitions at:

```
@Entity
public class PlaceSaved {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  private int id;

  @ColumnInfo(name = "time")
  private String time;

  @ColumnInfo(name="title")
  private String title;

  public PlaceSaved(){

  }

  public PlaceSaved(String time, String title) {
    this.time = time;
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getTime() {
    return time;
  }

  public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

the corresponding DAO is:

```
@Dao
public interface DatabaseInterface {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM placesaved")
  List<PlaceSaved> getAllItems();

  @Insert
  void insertAll(PlaceSaved... todoListItems);
  @Delete
  public void delete(PlaceSaved... todoListItems);
  @Update
  public void update(PlaceSaved...todoListItems);
}
```

and those data are displayed via a recyclerview with each item layout defined as:

```
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/secondLine"/>
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"/>
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/delicon"/>
```

Now, I want to use this `delicon` `ImageButton` to delete the corresponding entry.
So, I tried to put this in my Adapter as (**NOTE: Updated, see Updated code at the end**):

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //PlaceDatabase db;
    List<PlaceSaved> items;

    public PlacesAdapter(List<PlaceSaved> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.places_list_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.name.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.time.setText(items.get(position).getTime());
//        holder.delbutton.setClickable(true);
        holder.delbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          removeItem(items);
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView name;
        public TextView time;
        public ImageButton delbutton;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            time= itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            delbutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delicon);

        }
    }
    private void removeItem(PlaceSaved infoItem){
      PlaceSaved placeSaved = new PlaceSaved();
      placeSaved.delete(infoItem);
    }
}
```

and the recyclerview is called as: (**Note: onCreate is updated and posted at the end)

```
public class PlacesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton fab, fab1, fab2, fab3;
    LinearLayout fabLayout1, fabLayout2, fabLayout3;
    boolean isFABOpen=false;
    View fabBGLayout;
  public static RecyclerView recyclerView;
  public static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
  List<PlaceSaved> items;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.places_layout);

    //whenever the activity is started, it reads data from database and stores it into
    // local array list 'items'
    final PlaceDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), PlaceDatabase.class, "production")
        .build();

    //it is very bad practice to pull data from Room on main UI thread,
    // that's why we create another thread which we use for getting the data and displaying it
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        items = db.databaseInterface().getAllItems();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication()));
        adapter = new PlacesAdapter(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
    };
```

This gives compilation time error:

```
PlacesAdapter.java
Error:(43, 22) error: incompatible types: List<PlaceSaved> cannot be converted to PlaceSaved
Error:(68, 17) error: cannot find symbol method delete(PlaceSaved)
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

**UPDATE**
By Vishu's answer, I have updated my adapter as:

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

  List<PlaceSaved> items;
  PlaceDatabase db;
  public PlacesAdapter(List<PlaceSaved> items, PlaceDatabase db) {
    this.items = items;
    this.db = db;
  }

    @Override
    public PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
          .inflate(R.layout.places_list_item,parent,false);
      return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      holder.name.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.time.setText(items.get(position).getTime());
        holder.delbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        removeItem(items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
      public TextView name;
      public TextView time;
      public ImageButton delbutton;

      public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        time= itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        delbutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delicon);

      }
    }
    private void removeItem(PlaceSaved infoItem){
//      db.delete(infoItem);
      Log.v(TAG, "remove Item called");
    }
}
```

and in PlacesActivity:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.places_layout);

    final PlaceDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), PlaceDatabase.class, "production")
        .build();

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        items = db.databaseInterface().getAllItems();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication()));
        adapter = new PlacesAdapter(items, db);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
    };
```

which is still giving syntax error :

```
Error:(71, 17) error: cannot find symbol method delete(PlaceSaved)
```

and 2 warning (not due to Vishu's answer, it was present before):

```
PlaceSaved.java
Warning:(11, 8) There are multiple good constructors and Room will pick the no-arg constructor. You can use the @Ignore annotation to eliminate unwanted constructors.

PlaceDatabase.java
Warning:(13, 17) Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
```

Error: Update:
adding                 `db.databaseInterface().delete(infoItem);` 
in removeitem gives:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
      at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:164)                                                                             
     at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:211)
     at DatabaseInterface_Impl.delete(DatabaseInterface_Impl.java:94)
     at PlacesAdapter.removeItem(PlacesAdapter.java:69)
     at PlacesAdapter.access$000(PlacesAdapter.java:20)
     at PlacesAdapter$1.onClick(PlacesAdapter.java:45)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why are you passing `ArrayList` of `PlaceSaved` in `removeItem()`. `removeItem()` accept only `PlaceSaved`.

So change your `onclick` to

```
removeItem(items.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
```

make `holder` final in method signature `final PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder holder` else it won't compile.

You have defined `delete` in  `PlaceDatabase` and you are calling on `PlaceSaved` that's why you are getting `Error:(68, 17) error: cannot find symbol method delete(PlaceSaved)`

you can pass `db` from in `PlacesAdapter` just like `items` like `PlacesAdapter(items, db)`

change

```
adapter = new PlacesAdapter(items);
```

to

```
adapter = new PlacesAdapter(items, db);
```

Now your PlacesAdapter will have `db` instance. and you can  replce `placeSaved.delete(infoItem);` with `db.delete(infoItem)`

Change

```
List<PlaceSaved> items;
public PlacesAdapter(List<PlaceSaved> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

to

```
List<PlaceSaved> items;
PlaceDatabase db;
public PlacesAdapter(List<PlaceSaved> items, PlaceDatabase db) {
    this.items = items;
    this.db = db
}
```

And 
Change

```
 placeSaved.delete(infoItem);
```

to

```
db.databaseInterface().delete(infoItem);
```

Comment: hi Vishu, thanks for your comment. But I still don't understand how to pass the database. I have changed the OnClick, which is now valid, but the removeItem method is still giving error:
Error:(69, 17) error: cannot find symbol method delete(PlaceSaved)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Updated answer!!

Comment: Vishu, thanks for your reply once again. The change PlacesAdapter(items, db) gives error:
Error:(44, 19) error: constructor PlacesAdapter in class PlacesAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: List<PlaceSaved>
found: List<PlaceSaved>,PlaceDatabase
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Change the constructor as described in answer

Comment: Hi, Thnaks a lot. Now, my removeItem looks like:
   `private void removeItem(PlaceSaved infoItem){
      db.delete(infoItem);
      Log.v(TAG, "remove Item called");
    }` 
no error, but not deleting the item either.

Comment: oh...no...sorry, actually, still, the in removeItem , can not resolve db.delete()

Comment: if you have some time, can we move to chat?

Comment: I have updated the Adapter and ACtivity. Please, can you kindly have a look?

Comment: are you there? can you kindly have a look again?

Comment: use this `db.databaseInterface().delete(infoItem);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166441/discussion-between-barud-and-vishu).

Comment: that gives runtime error. Probably I need to do asyncTask, right? can you kindly help me a bit with that?

Comment: thanks a lot. Its working fine. Only one thing is that its not updating right then. I have to close the screen and come back again to see the effect, even after including `notifydatasetchanged()`. Any idea?